# sum values in a column with if statement in Excel

Tags: excel, sum

I need to sum the integer values in a column in my excel spreadsheet. I also need to consider 2 to be 1. for example, I have the following column:

```
./.
./.

1
2
2
./.
./.

./.
0
```

To get the sum, I need: sum(A1:A11), but how do I count 2 as 1 for the summation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about other numbers, does 3 count as 3....or are there only 1s and 2s? if the latter perhaps use COUNTIF like this

`=COUNTIF(A2:A10,">=1")`

Comment: the entries are only four possibilities: 0, 1, 2, and ./.

Comment: Thank you very much. This formula works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make a second column with a formula like

```
=IF(A1=2;1;A1)
```